# Using sns.pairplot hue

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn

```
df = pd.read_csv('model_predictions.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)
df = df.rename(columns={7: 'label'})
sns.set(style='ticks')
sns.pairplot(df, hue="label")
plt.show()
```

I am using this code to generate a pairplot and want to change the color to use the values from 'label' column, but am getting error below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\krock\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>     File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>     File "pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
>   KeyError: 'label'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/krock/PycharmProjects/test/aaa.py", line 9, in 
>       sns.pairplot(df.loc[:, 0:6], hue="label")   File "C:\Users\krock\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py",
>   line 2094, in pairplot
>       height=height, aspect=aspect, dropna=dropna, **grid_kws)   File "C:\Users\krock\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py",
>   line 1333, in **init**
>       hue_names = utils.categorical_order(data[hue], hue_order)   File "C:\Users\krock\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 2800, in **getitem**
>       indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:\Users\krock\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
>   line 2648, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 135, in
>   pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
>   "pandas_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in
>   pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type KeyError: 'label'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I don't know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that python can't find the column `label` in your subset `df.loc[:, 0:7]`.

Try to use full dataset instead, or make sure that your subset contains the `label` column.

Comment: I tried using the whole dataset, but still get the same error.

Comment: Could you share some lines of your `.csv` file? So I can test it here

Comment: I got the point: set the parameter `inplace=True` in your `rename` function.